# How to call PL/SQL Packages (Not stored procedure or function) with JPA

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, plsql, jpa-2.0

i've already made a search for this, but i didn't have my answer yet.
Nor saying this woulnd't works. All i can find is bunch examples how to call function or stored procedure.

So i have packages in PL\SQL and i want to call it in JPA Hibernate.
Is there a way to call it?

Regards,

Ivan

Comment: You don't call "a package", you call a procedure _in_ a package - and that is is the same as calling "regular" procedures except that you need to prefix the procedure name with the package name.

Answer (score 0):

You have to prefix the package name with function/procedure name and if you are trying to fetch certain value then you have to run
"select pkg_name.fun_name from dual".